# EF Core - Get Employees and Managers of a branch in single query

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have three tables - Branch, Employees and Managers.

Employees and Managers belong to a branch and so have branchID column in it. So tables are like below:

Branch:

| ID | Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Delhi | NewDelhi |
| 2 | Pune | Baner |

Manager:

| ID | Name | Salary | BranchId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3000 | 1 |
| 2 | Matt | 2000 | 1 |
| 3 | Rachel | 2500 | 2 |

Employee

| ID | Name | Salary | BranchId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Suraj | 1500 | 1 |
| 2 | Abhijeet | 2000 |  |

Though, employee and Manager tables look same, there's reason we have kept them separate and other columns are not shown here.

Now the requirement is to get result as below:

| BranchName | TotalEmployeesofBranch | TotalManagersOfbranch | TotalSalaryGiventoEmployees+managers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Delhi | 1 | 2 | 6500 |
| Pune | 1 | 1 | 4500 |

I am able to get two separate results for Employee and Manager, but again, not able to combine it.

We are using EF Core with Postgres Database. Database query solutions are also welcome and we can see if we can convert them into EF Core query.

---

TLDR update: as requested in comments, posting the classes:
Branch:

```
namespace InvestorSystem.DataModel.Table
{
    public class Branch
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public long BranchManagerID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Employee:

```
namespace InvestorSystem.DataModel.Table
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }

        public long PersonID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
        public virtual Person? Person { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BankDetailsID")]
        public long? BankDetailsID { get; set; }
        public BankDetails? BankDetails { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("NomineeID")]
        public long? NomineeID { get; set; }
        public Nominee? Nominee { get; set; }


        public int? BranchID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BranchID")]
        public Branch? Branch { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Manager:

```
namespace InvestorSystem.DataModel.Table
{
    public class Manager
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
        public long? PersonID { get; set; }
        public virtual Person? Person { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BankDetailsID")]
        public long? BankDetailsID { get; set; }
        public BankDetails? BankDetails { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("NomineeID")]
        public long? NomineeID { get; set; }
        public Nominee? Nominee { get; set; }

        public int? BranchId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BranchId")]
        public Branch? Branch { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Dai what did you do differently, my tables were visible in preview but not after I submit.

Comment: It's a bug in StackOverflow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372897/incomplete-table-markdown-causes-preview-to-appear-fine-while-its-broken-when-p

Comment: take a screenshot and post the table ?

Comment: @Sund'er I would, but there are too many other columns which will decrease readablity.. So only mentioned the needed columns.

Comment: "my tables were visible in preview" take this screen shot before submit it has limited columns right?

Comment: @Sund'er please ingore that.. It was just question formatting error. Let's focus on actual question now.

Comment: Show model classes. Especially navigation properties. LINQ Query is built from classes.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, As said in earlier comment, it contains many other properties, which will create confusion. Also, these are not exactly my tables, it's just dummy example for easy imagination.

Comment: @SurajS Svjatoslav is right, in order to help you with LINQ query, we need classes, not tables. They doesn't need to be real, but must show relevant properties. For instance, in EF Core entity model the `Branch` class would have collection navigation properties for `Employees` and `Managers`, so the desired query would be simply starting with `Branch` db set and selecting some aggregates of these "collections",  e.g. `branch.Employeess.Count()`, `branch.Employees.Sum(emp => emp.Salary)` etc.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have added the models

Comment: @IvanStoev I have added the models

Comment: @SurajS Any reason of not having the aforementioned collection navigation properties in `Branch`? e.g. `public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }` and `public virtual ICollection<Manager> Managers{ get; set; }`? Because with them the query in question is trivial, otherwise we have to write joins/subqueries or `GroupBy` etc., which normally are not needed in LINQ to Entities (EF Core) queries.

Comment: @IvanStoev as Branch has Employees as well as Managers, I have to add both Navigation properties. Which could have become complex. Also, I though it is useful when I want Employee.Person.Firstname and other things can be achieved via Group by.

Now, the salaries I mentioned are actually store in different table.. May be Employee_Salary and Manager_salary.. we need it's sum too so that needs to be addressed too.

Comment: @SurajS Of course it needs both collections in `Branch`. These has to be added there. I'm not saying you need to remove something, i.e. `Employee.Branch` and `Manager.Branch` will stay. Then the query would be something like `db.Set<Branch>().Select(b => new { b.Name, TotalEmployees = b.Employees.Count(), TotalManagers = b.Managers.Count(), TotalSalary = b.Employees.Sum(e => e.Salary) + b.Managers.Sum(m => m.Salary) }`. Hope you got the idea.